# How to add a record simultaneously in another table when a new blog post is inserted using wp_insert_post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding a new blog post using `wp_insert_post`. Is it possible to show a notification message to all the other users that a person posted a new blog post.

I need to insert a record in another table when `wp_insert_post` function occurs.

I am trying to do Follow feature. If some user is following me, he should get my newly added blog post as a notification.

Any helps...!!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wp_insert_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post) hook.
As it says in the docs: The `wp_insert_post` action fires once a post has been saved.

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // If this is a revision, don't send the email.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $subject = 'A post has been updated';

    $message = "A post has been updated on your website:\n\n";
    $message .= $post->post_title . ": " . $post_url;

    // Send email to admin.
    wp_mail( 'admin@example.com', $subject, $message );
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email', 10, 3 );
```